# change numeric vector

Tags: r, vector, numeric

I have a numeric vector (see below). I would like to change all numbers that are assigned to high_ to 1 and all low_ to 2.

```
c(high_X17 = 3, high_X18 = 4, high_X19 = 5, high_X20 = 3, high_X21 = 1, 
high_X22 = 1, high_X23 = 2, high_X24 = 2, low_X25 = 6, low_X26 = 4, 
low_X27 = 6, low_X28 = 5, low_X29 = 2, low_X30 = 1, low_X31 = 1, 
low_X32 = 2)
```

result

```
high_X17 high_X18 high_X19 high_X20 high_X21 high_X22 high_X23 high_X24  low_X25  low_X26  
       1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        2        2        
 low_X29  low_X30  low_X31  low_X32 
       2        2        2        2
```

Comment: I think if you dput the structure here things will go smoother.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below

```
x <- startsWith(names(x),"low_") + 1
```

Comment: And how one could apply it to a list?

Comment: @giegie you'd better `dput` your list data.

Comment: ok done, you can see it in the original question

Comment: your `c(...` isn't a list, so this answer still works. Were `my_high_low` a list, slipping an unlist in would do the trick `startsWith(names(unlist(my_high_low_lst)), 'low_') + 1`. Returns a vector.

Comment: It gives sth like this [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2, without names

Comment: @giegie Try `setNames(startsWith(names(x),"low_") + 1, names(x))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use -

```
x[] <- as.integer(sub('_.*', '', names(x)) == 'low') + 1
x

#high_X17 high_X18 high_X19 high_X20 high_X21 high_X22 high_X23 high_X24 
#       1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1 

# low_X25  low_X26  low_X27  low_X28  low_X29  low_X30  low_X31  low_X32 
#       2        2        2        2        2        2        2        2
```

`sub('_.*', '', names(x))` removes everything after underscore keeping only `'high'` and `'low'` values.

Answer (score 0):

Using `grepl`

```
grepl("low_", names(x)) + 1
```